# Which version does React Native support (iOS and Android)?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile-application, mobile-development

I can't find this information. Is it true that Android React Native runs on sdkMin18 and therefore makes it supported by most android versions?

Comment: Just to add on @Murat Karagöz 's answer... Here is where the React Native minSdk support changed: - version 0.64.0 supports minSdk 21, Android 5.0 or newer - version 0.63.4 supports minSdk 16, Android 4.1 or newer https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You can run it on minSdk 21 as it is documented on [the framework's github page](https://github.com/facebook/react-native#-requirements).

> React Native apps may target iOS 11.0 and Android 5.0 (API 21) or newer.

Comment: Thanks, I'm really a beginner so can you tell me please what is the meaning of API 16??

Comment: @Joe Tha'ts the sdk version. In this case it reflects on Android 4.1. So devices which are not 4.1 or higher will not be able to run the app.

Comment: For iOS, it's now 9.0

Comment: as a follow up to @BhavukJain 's answer per [this](https://github.com/react-native-community/releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) change log as of version 0.63.0 `Deprecate iOS 9.x support (58a6a40eac, 829a2237d2, 674b591809 by @fkgozali, d1265077d6 by @sunnylqm)`. Based on that, I would say that iOS is supported until 0.63.0.

Answer (score 18):

- for February 2020:
- React Native apps may target iOS 10.0 and Android 4.1 (API 16) or
  newer.
- Expo supports Android 5+ and iOS 10+.

Answer (score 5):

The supported iOS version changes all the time, but you can find it at any time by checking the Podfile on the official repository:

## October 2023

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/packages/react-native/scripts/cocoapods/helpers.rb#L41

## March 2023

As of 2023, the min version can be found there:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/packages/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb#L41

## December 2021

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/template/ios/Podfile

For example, as of December 2021, the supported iOS version is 11.0.

Comment: it is 12.0 now right, in aug of 2022

Comment: Link is wrong now.

Comment: link updated again.